# How to Recognize a Hold Button {iPhone SDK}

Tags: iphone, sdk

Hi i have a Button i want hold this button to write something but i don't know how can i recognize hold button , can you help me ? thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TouchDownInside event triggered, start a NStimer.
TouchUpInside event triggered, cancel the timer.
Make the timer call your method to execute if the user holds the button : the timer delay will be the amount of time required to recognize hold.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

In your initialization method (e.g. `viewDidLoad`), create a gesture recognizer and attach it to your button:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
  initWithTarget:self 
  action:@selector(myButtonLongPressed:)];
// you can control how many seconds before the gesture is recognized  
gesture.minimumPressDuration = 2; 
// attach the gesture to your button
[myButton addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
[gesture release];
```

The event handler `myButtonLongPressed:` should look like this:

```
- (void) myButtonLongPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
  // Button was long pressed, do something
}
```

Note that `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is a [continuous event recognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319591/uilongpressgesturerecognizer-gets-called-twice-when-pressing-down).
While the user is still holding down the button, `myButtonLongPressed:` will be called multiple times. 
If you just want to handle the first call, you can check the state in `myButtonLongPressed:`:

```
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
  // Button was long pressed, do something
}
```