# Callout within UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, user-interface, callout

I am looking for a iOS Music app style Callout functionality. What I mean with that is that I want to get the same kind of callout "bubble" you get when press-and-hold within the Music app on iOS5.

I have been searching for a good solution for this, but can't find it.

The closest to what I need is: [Use UITableView bubble/callout like iPod app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124650/use-uitableview-bubble-callout-like-ipod-app) However, this user didn't share what solution he had.

The libs I have looked at are:

- https://github.com/jayway/CWUIKit
- https://github.com/edanuff/MonoTouchCalloutView
- http://www.eidac.de/?p=183

All of these have one this in common: They are useless. 
The problem with these are that they all use a static callout view using PNG images, not one with a pointer beneath. Also, they do not adapt to the size of the screen; thus the bubble gets outside of the screen.

Any suggestions on a good library which I can use to implements this within my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about WEPopover?
It might be what you want.
[WEPopover for iOS](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/wepopover)

Comment: Allthough its way better then the others I tried... it is not exactly what I am looking for. I basically want exactly the iPod apps functionality.