# How to disable allowableMovement property of uilongpressgesture in iphone

Tags: iphone

hi in my application i have to disable the longpress gesture allowableMovement property i dont have any idea how to disable this. if anyone know please let me know. thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean `allowableMovement`?  What does "disable" mean - do you want to allow no movement?

Comment: yes i don't want to allow to track finger movement after long press using the long press gesture.

Comment: So the scenario is: user touches UI; user holds finger steady for a while; action is fired on target; at this point you want to stop the gesture recognizer tracking the finger?  Why?  What else are you expecting to happen now?

Comment: yes ur correct. Actually my requirement is when ever the user perform long press on an imageview popover will launch at that point , here after that based on finger moment that popover also moving around the view. that i want to disable. so please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: I haven't looked too closely into this area.  Can you set up another gesture recognizer for the popover that has requireGestureRecognizerToFail: set on this one?

Comment: how can i use another gesture because i have to launch that popover after long press. so as per my knowledge long press gesture is only the gesture i can use here. if we can use any other gesture for this requirement pls let me know.

Comment: Hang on. Is the problem actually that your action method on the long press recognizer gets fired over and over again?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem you are seeing may be that some gesture recognizers are designed to fire multiple times as long as the gesture they recognize is still true.  So a long press is a long press at 1 second, still a long press at 2 seconds, etc.

You should check the `state` of the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` in your action method, as described here:

[UILongPressGestureRecognizer gets called twice when pressing down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319591/uilongpressgesturerecognizer-gets-called-twice-when-pressing-down)