# UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan calling twice in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, retina-display

Giving thanks in advance, I would like to share the strange behaviour of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

```
UIView *v = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressGesture1 = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
[v addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture1];
```

and here the delegate to handle the gesture recogniser.

```
-(IBAction)tapped:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *) gesture

{ 
    switch ([gesture state]) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        {

            NSLog(@"Long Tap detacted.");  

        }
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        {
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged");


        }
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        {
            NSLog(@"Long Tap ended.");

        }
            break;

    }

}
```

This piece of code is working perfectly as expected in iOS 4 and 5, but in ios 6  with retina display when we perform the long tap, `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` is being called twice for a single long tap resulting in a application crash. 
Any help  is greatly welcome.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3320351/792677 Feel free to provide and accept an answer with the fixed code.

Answer (score 2):

**UILongPressGestureRecognizer is a continuous event recognizer. You have to look at the state to see if this is the start, middle or end of the event and act accordingly.**

Its calling two times because you are pressing and removing your finger.

First call is indicating you that there is an Long tap detected i.e. `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`
Second call is indicating you that  there is end of that tap i.e. `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`

There are three state of tap

1. `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`
2. `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`
3. `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`

If you will drag your finger then it will called multiple time that will indicate that there is some changes in its state.

Follow [UILongPressGestureRecognizer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for  more

Comment: No, I am not pressing and removing the fingers. It happens on a same event i.e pressing.  That's why it working on iOS4 and ios5 but not in ios6

Comment: when you are pressing finger then its indicating that an event is happening and after finishing your long press its indicating end of tap

Comment: I haven't reached finishing tap. I am still holding  long tap.

Comment: i tried your code with iOS 6 and output in nslog is Long Tap detacted. and Long Tap ended.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I too expected the same in all the version of ios. But i failed to received it in iOS 6 with retina display.