# UILongPressGestureRecognizer Error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've connected a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to my Button on the view. I did this in the Referencing Outlet Collections in in the Interface Builder.
When the Button gets pressed an Action is triggered:

```
 - (IBAction)longPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nextView" sender:self];
}
```

The segue was created in the Interfacebuilder.

The next ViewController is pushed (I use a NavigationController) and displayed correct.
But now I get this Error Message:

"nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar"
"Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted."
"Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for ."

When I press the back Button the App crashes.

I tried to trigger the segue with a simple Button touch. It works, but why does it crash with the LongPress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logPressed gets called multiple times with different states.  You need to add code in there to only fire the event for one of the states.

[Read up on this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3320351/1671729)

And put in code something like this with whatever state you want to accept.

```
-  (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender { 
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
      NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
    //Do Whatever You want on End of Gesture
     }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
       NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.");
   //Do Whatever You want on Began of Gesture
     }
  }
```

I would suggest this state: `UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized`

Comment: You can accept the answer if it completely solved the question.